# How to colorise PowerShell output of Format-Table

Tags: powershell, colors, console

I try to colorise the column RAM in red if the value is greater than 100 MB:

```
Get-Process | Format-Table @{ Label = "PID"; Expression={$_.Id}},
            @{ Label = "Name"; Expression={$_.Name}},
            @{ Label = "RAM (MB)"; Expression={[System.Math]::Round($_.WS/1MB, 1)}},
            @{ Label = "Responding"; Expression={$_.Responding}}
```

[image]

I try with **Write-Host -nonewline**, but the result is wrong.

```
Get-Process | Format-Table @{ Label = "PID"; Expression={$_.Id}},
            @{ Label = "Name"; Expression={$_.Name}},
            @{ Label = "RAM (MB)"; Expression={write-host -NoNewline $([System.Math]::Round($_.WS/1MB, 1)) -ForegroundColor red}},
            @{ Label = "Responding"; Expression={ write-host -NoNewline $_.Responding -fore red}}
```

[image]

Comment: And what is the result? Please post a screenshot.

Comment: Have a read of this article, it may help http://www.powershellmagazine.com/2013/06/20/an-example-when-using-write-host-makes-sense/

Comment: I supplied an answer but it doesnt color columns, just rows.

Comment: You can colorize columns differently, the accepted answer is no longer true, you need to use Write-PSObject. See my answer below.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### You could colorize *the row* making use of a regular expression...

```
filter colorize-row{

    Get-Process | Select-Object Id, Name, WS, Responding | foreach {

        # Print 'red' row if WS greater than 100 MB
        if([System.Math]::Round($_.WS/1MB,1) -match "^([0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[1-9][0-9]?$|^100$)$"){
            [console]::ForegroundColor="white"; $_;
        } else {
            [console]::ForegroundColor="red"; $_;
        }
    }
}

colorize-row
```

### Output:

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to format like when using `Format-Table`?  I tried the `@{n="<heading>"; e={$_.<value>}; a="left"}` syntax, but it doesn't work.

Comment: This answer is no longer true, you can colorize columns, see my answer.

Answer (score 44):

Starting with PowerShell 5.1 or later you can use [VT escape sequences](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences#span-idtextformattingspanspan-idtextformattingspanspan-idtextformattingspantext-formatting) to add colors to a single column, but only if your console supports VT escape sequences (e.g. Windows 10 Fall Creators Update, Linux or Mac, but not Windows 8 w/o a console emulator like ConEmu).

Here is an example that has the formatting specified in an expression, though the same could be used in a ps1xml file:

```
dir -Exclude *.xml $pshome | Format-Table Mode,@{
    Label = "Name"
    Expression =
    {
        switch ($_.Extension)
        {
            '.exe' { $color = "93"; break }
            '.ps1xml' { $color = '32'; break }
            '.dll' { $color = "35"; break }
           default { $color = "0" }
        }
        $e = [char]27
       "$e[${color}m$($_.Name)${e}[0m"
    }
 },Length
```

And the resulting output, note that the column width looks good, there are no extra spaces from the escape sequence characters.

[image: Screenshot of dir output with colored names]

Comment: There was an announcement about (maybe) 16bit support. Is that related to this feature, or something different?

Comment: Yes, 256 and 24bit color is supported by some terminals, the link in my answer describes that as well.

Comment: this is pure gold. thx! what i made from it https://gist.github.com/SeidChr/6dcae356760197d3d9147a3414829945

Comment: If anyone's tempted to declare the magic strings & numbers and improve readability, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347214/pass-arguments-to-a-scriptblock-in-powershell.

Answer (score 20):

The accepted answer is incorrect, it is possible to colorize columns. The solution to getting conditional column colors is to use [Write-PSObject](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2008.06.windowspowershell.aspx).

[Here are some wonderful examples](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Format-Table-Colors-in-e0a4beac) with documented code and explanations.

From the above resource:

```
Write-PSObject $servers -MatchMethod Exact -Column "Manufacture" -Value "HP" -ValueForeColor Yellow -ValueBackColor Red -RowForeColor White -RowBackColor Blue;
```

[image]

I found this via [a GitHub issue to add color formatting to Format-Table](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/3886), which seems to be a feature PowerShell devs would like to add at some point.

Comment: It seems the links in your answer no longer point to the right place, only the GitHub issue is still correct.

Answer (score 4):

The quick answer is that you can't. It's possible to use [Write-Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Write-Host?view=powershell-5.1) with colors, but there's no "output" to send to format-table.

The "output" from Write-Host is a side-effect that sends data directly to the console rather than returning it to the caller like a standard function.

In conjunction with the comment by @David Martin, here's [a link](http://www.bgreco.net/powershell/format-color/) with an interesting pattern-matching format-color function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a different version of [Jason Shirk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49038815/21243735) after a few years now using [PSStyle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_ansi_terminals) in PowerShell 7.4

[image]

```
# Create a dummy data table with three columns: Name, Age, and Occupation
$data = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'Alice'; Age = 25; Occupation = 'Teacher' }
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'Bob'; Age = 30; Occupation = 'Engineer' }
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'Charlie'; Age = 35; Occupation = 'Doctor' }
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'David'; Age = 40; Occupation = 'Lawyer' }
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name = 'Eve'; Age = 45; Occupation = 'Artist' }
)

$PSStyle.Formatting.TableHeader = "$($PSStyle.Foreground.FromRGB(218,112,214))"

$data | Format-Table @{
    Label      = 'Name'
    Expression =
    { switch ($_.Name) {
            { $_ } { $color = "$($PSStyle.Foreground.FromRGB(255,255,49))$($PSStyle.Blink)" } # Use PSStyle to set the color
        }
        "$color$($_.Name)$($PSStyle.Reset)" # Use PSStyle to reset the color
    }
}, @{
    Label      = 'Age'
    Expression =
    { switch ($_.age) {
            { $_ -gt 30 } { $color = "$($PSStyle.Foreground.FromRGB(255,20,147))$($PSStyle.Blink)" } # Use PSStyle to set the color
        }
        "$color$($_.age)$($PSStyle.Reset)" # Use PSStyle to reset the color
    }
}, @{
    Label      = 'Occupation'
    Expression =
    { switch ($_.Occupation) {
            { $_ } { $color = "$($PSStyle.Foreground.FromRGB(152,255,152))$($PSStyle.Blink)" } # Use PSStyle to set the color
        }
        "$color$($_.Occupation)$($PSStyle.Reset)" # Use PSStyle to reset the color
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use ANSI Escape colors and have the colors conditional:

```
Get-Process | Format-Table @{ Label = "PID"; Expression={$_.Id}},
        @{ Label = "Name"; Expression={$_.Name}},
        @{ Label = "RAM (MB)"; Expression={if($_.WS/1MB -gt 100){"$([char]27)[0;31m$([System.Math]::Round($_.WS/1MB, 1))$([char]27)[0m"}else{"$([char]27)[0;32m$([System.Math]::Round($_.WS/1MB, 1))$([char]27)[0m"}}},
        @{ Label = "Responding"; Expression={if($_.Responding -eq $true){"$([char]27)[0;32m$($_.Responding)$([char]27)[0m"}else{"$([char]27)[0;31m$($_.Responding)$([char]27)[0m"}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This example shows event records with alternating background colours of the rows (thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62088948/how-to-show-the-row-or-line-number-in-powershell-format-table)).
Based on the TimeCreated field, the text colour will be blue (one month or less), yellow (one week or less) or red (today).
See the 'ANSI Escape code' subject on Wikipedia for colour escape codes.

```
# constants
$e=[char]27                                             # escape character
[string]$_Reset     = $($e+"[0m")
[string]$_bSapphire1= $($e+"[48;2;1;36;86m")        # ESC[48;2;r;g;bm Select RGB background colour
[string]$_bSapphire2= $($e+"[48;2;3;55;155m")
[string]$_fBRed     = $($e+"[91m")
[string]$_fBYellow  = $($e+"[93m")
[string]$_fBCyan    = $($e+"[96m")
$Today              = [datetime]::today
$OneWeek            = $Today.AddDays(-7)
$OneMonth           = $Today.AddDays(-30)
# variable
[ref]$bToggle       = $True                         # makes the background colour of the row alternate
# script block
$ExtractScript={
    param([array]$Events,[enum]$Level)
    $Events|
    Where-Object { $Level -eq $_.Level }|
    Sort-Object -Property @{ Expression="ProviderName"; Ascending=$True },
                          @{ Expression="TimeCreated" ; Ascending=$True }|
    Format-Table @{
            Label="TimeCreated"
            Expression= {
                # rows have an alternating background colour
                if($bToggle.Value) { $bcolour=[string]::copy($_bSapphire1) } else { $bcolour=[string]::copy($_bSapphire2) }
                $bToggle.Value = $(-not $bToggle.Value)
                
                # TimeCreated has effect on the foreground colour of the row 
                $fcolour = [string]::copy($_Reset)
                if( $OneMonth -lt $_.TimeCreated ) { $fcolour = [string]::copy($_fBCyan) }
                if( $OneWeek  -lt $_.TimeCreated ) { $fcolour = [string]::copy($_fBYellow) }
                if( $Today    -lt $_.TimeCreated ) { $fcolour = [string]::copy($_fBRed) }
                $($fcolour+$bcolour+$("{0:d} {0:HH}:{0:mm}:{0:ss}" -f $($_.TimeCreated)))
            }
            Alignment='Right'
        },
        ProviderName,
        ID,
        @{
            Name='Level'
            Expression={$_.LevelDisplayName}
            Alignment='Right'
        },
        @{
            Name='Message'
            Expression={
                # Colours are reset
                $($_.Message+$_Reset)
            }
        }       
}
# code
$EventArray=Get-WinEvent -LogName System -MaxEvents 10000
& $ExtractScript -Events $EventArray -Level $([System.Diagnostics.Eventing.Reader.StandardEventLevel]::Error)
$($_Reset+"Legend:")|Out-Default
$($_fBCyan+"After "+$("{0:d} {0:HH}:{0:mm}:{0:ss}" -f $OneMonth))|Out-Default
$($_fBYellow+"After "+$("{0:d} {0:HH}:{0:mm}:{0:ss}" -f $OneWeek))|Out-Default
$($_fBRed+"Today")|Out-Default   
$_Reset|Out-Default
```