# How to get Get-Process in PowerShell property vm in megabytes?

Tags: powershell

I'm going to write command in PowerShell, which will output my process name and virtual memory. I need to change my value vm to megabytes.

```
Get-Process| Sort VM | Format-Table -p name,VM
```

And I have this

```
Name                                                                                    VM
----                                                                                    --
Idle                                                                                     0
smss                                                                               3121152
System                                                                             6053888
AEADISRV                                                                          18485248
lsm                                                                               23670784
SearchFilterHost                                                                  24240128
svchost                                                                           27344896
svchost                                                                           27922432
wininit                                                                           31449088
svchost                                                                           34127872
armsvc                                                                            34938880
lsass                                                                             35885056
WUDFHost                                                                          36036608
csrss                                                                             36552704
winlogon                                                                          37531648
svchost                                                                           37638144
```

Also I need to change color if process has > 100 Mb VM

Comment: For color, better filter. For MBs, use select expression `{$_.VM/1MB}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Format-Table` cmdlet doesn't support coloring. What you can do is to [change color for each row](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20707761).

If you are willing to give up the nice table format, pass the results to pipeline and use `Write-Host -ForegroundColor` to specify colors on cell level. Like so,

```
gwmi win32_process | select name,processid,vm | % {
$params = @{ Object = $_ }
$mem = $params["Object"].VM/1MB
if([int]$mem -ge 100 ) {
    write-host -nonewline -foregroundcolor yellow $mem " "
} else {
    write-host -nonewline $mem " "
}
write-host $params["Object"].name " " $params["Object"].processid
}
```

Another an approach is based on saving the result on some temporary medium and add coloring later. This requires a bit more code. Petri has [a nice example](https://www.petri.com/color-coding-with-powershell) with more code than I'm willing to copypaste here.