# How to show the row or line number in powershell format-table

Tags: powershell

I'd like the data presented by format-table to include the line or row number of the items.
How can I achieve this?

some-command | ft

```
Line    Something       Else
----    ---------       ----
0       Item1           Property1
1       Item2           Property2
```

Answer (score 2):

You coiuld loop through the data and prepend an extra property `Line` to the output using a counter variable.

Something like this:

```
# demo data
$data = [PsCustomObject]@{'Something' = 'Item1'; 'Else' = 'Property1'},
        [PsCustomObject]@{'Something' = 'Item2'; 'Else' = 'Property2'},
        [PsCustomObject]@{'Something' = 'Item3'; 'Else' = 'Property3'}

$count = 0
$data | ForEach-Object {
    $_ |  Select-Object @{Name = 'Line'; Expression = {$count}}, *
    $count++
} | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Output:

```
Line Something Else     
---- --------- ----     
   0 Item1     Property1
   1 Item2     Property2
   2 Item3     Property3
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking something like this:

```
[ref]$id = 0 ; @( @{ youritems='a' }, @{ youritems='b' }, @{ youritems='c' }) |ForEach-Object{ new-object PSObject -Property $_ } | Format-Table @{ n="SerialNumber"; e={ "{0}" -f ++$id.value }; a="left" },youritems
```

The output would be :

```
SerialNumber youritems
------------- ---------
1             a        
2             b        
3             c
```

Comment: so, assume I add a select -last 10 into the pipeline, wouldn't this make serial numbers inaccurate?

Comment: @simplex123:  Of course... If you comment out the reference ID = 0 , then it will not take the numbers accurately. There wont be any serial number generated. If you put -10, then serial numbers would be -9,-8,-7

Comment: Also, it is not something recommended to use -last 10 here because i gave a custom one now based on expression and values

Comment: @simplex123 you should pipe the objects to `Select -Last 10` _before_ piping to `Format-Table` anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take.  Some of my osx processes have no name as a regular user.

```
get-process | where name | 
  foreach { $line = 0 } { $line++; $_ } | 
  ft @{n='line';e={$line}}, name, id


line Name              Id
---- ----              --
   1 accountsd        368
   2 AirPlayUIAgent   508
   3 akd             2415
   4 AMPDeviceDiscov  412
   5 AppleSpell      1937
```

Take two:

```
ps | where name | select -first 5 | 
  foreach { $line = 0 } { $_ | add-member -passthru line (++$line) } |
  select line,name,id


line Name              Id
---- ----              --
   1 accountsd        368
   2 AirPlayUIAgent   508
   3 akd             2415
   4 AMPDeviceDiscov  412
   5 AppleSpell      1937
```