# Can I format a PSObject as a table with one row per property?

Tags: powershell

I'm using a simple PSObject:

```
$obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name A -Value 'x'
$obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name B -Value 'y'
```

I can format this as a table by simply writing `$obj`, or also by writing `Write-Host ($obj | Out-String)`:

```
A B
- -
x y
```

However, there now is one column per property rather than one *row* per property. That is, I want to have this output:

```
A : x
B : y
```

I have found resources that claim that's what will happen (e.g. [this tutorial](https://www.gngrninja.com/script-ninja/2016/6/18/powershell-getting-started-part-12-creating-custom-objects)), but it's not what happens when I try it.

**What am I doing wrong?**

---

To clarify my concern: If the property values become longer, the default formatting quickly gets "ugly", or even hard to read:

```
> $obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject
> $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name A -Value > 'https://abcdef/ghijkl/mnopqr/stuvwx?y=z'
> $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name B -Value 'https://abcdef/ghijkl/mnopqr/stuvwx?y=z'

> $obj

A                                       B
-                                       -
https://abcdef/ghijkl/mnopqr/stuvwx?y=z https://abcdef/ghijkl/mnopqr/stuvwx?y=z
```

Comment: What would be the expected output when, let's say, you get hundreds of members in the object ? Most likely nor readable if transposed like you wish.

Comment: @Civette: Uh, why? If there is one row per member (the formatting I want to get), I don't see a problem. It's rather that if there is one _column_ per member (the formatting I actually see), hundreds of members in the object will pose a problem, wouldn't you say? In the formatting as it is, I'm already expecting problems if there are just _two_ members in the object, but each of them contains a longer string than these one-letter-examples I showed above.

Comment: Sounds like you want `Format-List`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I suggest to create the object using

```
$obj = [pscustomobject]@{
    A = 'https://abcdef/ghijkl/mnopqr/stuvwx?y=z'
    B = 'https://abcdef/ghijkl/mnopqr/stuvwx?y=z'
}
```

Much easier to write, read and understand.

Second: calling the object will cause Powershell to automagically decide what's the best way to show it to you. Which is based on the number of properties, basically.

it's a DISPLAY issue: the best way to deal with this it tell Powershell "show me this stuff as a list" piping the object to `Format-List`:

```
PS > $obj | Format-List

A : https://abcdef/ghijkl/mnopqr/stuvwx?y=z
B : https://abcdef/ghijkl/mnopqr/stuvwx?y=z
```

(note: `Format-Table` does the opposite, telling Powershell to display the output as a table)

To actually force Powershell to always use the List format you'd need a Class.

Comment: It kind of works when I just write `$obj` like you did here. Unfortunately, if I use it in `Write-Host` (i.e. as `Write-Host ($obj | Format-List)`, the output is `Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupEndData Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEndData` ... anything do remedy that?

Comment: Sure: do not do that. Looks like a joke but it's not: Write-Host is not meant to be used.    
Let's go back: what you want to do, exactly?

Comment: Output an object, nicely formatted (as happens with your solution), optionally with a different foregound and/or background color (as is possible with `Write-Host` ).

Comment: That's a different question and you should make a new thread for it. Except it would be marked as "Duplicate", so have a freebie.  
  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20705102/how-to-colorise-powershell-output-of-format-table/49038815   It works with `format-list` as well

Comment: First, I was asking about a way to _format_ an object - which I'd have been happy to use with `Write-Host`, which also allows me to apply a color. I did not exactly ask for a _replacement_ of `Write-Host` that gives me proper formatting at the expense of the coloration capability, so there was no way to know up-front this is a different question. I'll consider asking a separate question. Second, thank you for the link, but that other question asks for more than I do; they want to color individual parts of the formatted output, whereas I just want to apply one color to the entire thing.

Comment: oh, absolutely you did right. I was saying that now you have a NEW question, which, I'm told, would mean opening a new topic. And You can just apply the coloring to the whole thing instead of just one part. Otherwise, to my knowledge, a Class is the only way out.