# Powershell start-job formatting issue

Tags: powershell, start-job

This is my first time using start-jobs, it is not working properly, am I using it wrong?

```
$dagName = "dag Name";
$dagObject = Get-DatabaseAvailabilityGroup -Identity $dagName;

$servers = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList;
foreach($server in $dagObject.Servers)
{
    $servers.Add($server) | Out-Null;
}

$getExchangeServers = @();
$getMailboxDatabases = @();
$getMailboxDatabasesWithStatus = @();

Start-Job -ScriptBlock {foreach ($server in $servers) {$getExchangeServers += get-exchangeserver $server;}}
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {foreach ($server in $servers) {$getMailboxDatabases += Get-MailboxDatabase -Server $server;}}
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {foreach ($server in $servers) {$getMailboxDatabasesWithStatus += Get-MailboxDatabase -Server $server -Status;}}
```

Comment: Yes, you are. Jobs are like completely separate PowerShell instances. They have no clue what `$servers` is, nor can they access any of the `$getMailboxDatabases` variables.

Comment: Ok thank you. How would you correct the code?

Could I do something like this?

    $results1 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {foreach ($server in $servers) {$getExchangeServers += get-exchangeserver $server;}} -ArgumentList $servers;

Comment: You would need a [`param` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347214/pass-arguments-to-a-scriptblock-in-powershell)

Comment: No you can't do that; You need to pass parameters in with `-ArgumentList` and change the scriptblocks to take parameters, and use `$AllResults = Get-Job | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob` to get their output and remove the jobs so they don't hang around after.

Comment: Ok, so I've tried this: (but to no avail) . It tells me it can't find the job. Would you mind providing a working example so I can build off of that?

$job1 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {foreach ($server in $servers) {$getExchangeServers += get-exchangeserver $server;}} -ArgumentList $servers;

$results1 = Get-Job -Name $job1 | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob

Comment: "Try this"  "I tried {something different} but it didn't work". hmm.  `$server = 'a','b','c'; Start-Job -ScriptBlock { param($p) foreach ($server in $p) { $server } } -ArgumentList @(,$Servers); $AllResults = Get-Job | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob; $AllResults` is a working example to just put some "server names" into a job and get them back.

Comment: So I tried

Start-Job -ScriptBlock { param($p) foreach ($server in $p) { $getExchangeServers += get-exchangeserver $server; } } -ArgumentList @(,$Servers); 
$AllResults = Get-Job | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob;

And it gave me the following error.

"The term 'get-exchangeserver' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet"

Does the script block also have to initialize a connection to the Exchange server?

Comment: I used this:  
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { param($p) $session1 = new-pssession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri 'http://xxxxxx/powershell'; import-pssession $session1 -AllowClobber; $getExchangeServers = @(); foreach ($server in $p) { $getExchangeServers += get-exchangeserver $server; } } -ArgumentList @(,$Servers);   
$AllResults = Get-Job | Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob;  
But $allResults equaled the name of the temporary Exchange powershell session that is established aka $session1

Comment: That's completely unhelpful Ansgar Wiechers, nicely done