# Run script on remote computer and pass creds to remote script

Tags: powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

Requirement: must be run from local machine on remote machine with creds passed to the remote machine script.

```
$server = 'SRV1'
$credential = Get-Credential
$credentials = Get-Credential
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $credential -ScriptBlock {
    C:\foo.ps1 $credentials
 }
```

foo.ps1 requires functions that need $credentials

Inside foo.ps1

```
param($credentials)
```

Comment: Problem is the remote script still asks for the credentials

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the Variable $credentials in the scriptBlock on the other computer without passing it as a parameter:
[Pass arguments to a scriptblock in powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16347214/pass-arguments-to-a-scriptblock-in-powershell)