# PowerShell pass a switch to a function with Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell

I'm having some difficulties passing the switch `-CleanFolders` to a function by using `Invoke-Command`. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225748/how-do-i-pass-named-parameters-with-invoke-command), but I don't really know how to implement it as it's not targeted to a function.

Calling my function like this works fine:

```
Delete-OldFiles $Target $OlderThanDays $Server -CleanFolders
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -Credential $Credentials -ScriptBlock ${Function:Delete-OldFiles} -ArgumentList ($Target, $OlderThanDays, $Server)
```

But this doesn't work at all:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -Credential $Credentials -ScriptBlock ${Function:Delete-OldFiles} -ArgumentList ($Target, $OlderThanDays, $Server, -CleanFolders)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$sb = {
  function Delete-OldFiles {
    #...
  }

  Delete-OldFiles $args[0] $args[1] $args[2] -CleanFolders:$args[3]
}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -Authentication Credssp `
  -Credential $Credentials -ScriptBlock $sb `
  -ArgumentList ($Target, $OlderThanDays, $Server, $true)
```

Comment: This seems to be only working when I change this `if ($CleanFolders)` to this `if ($CleanFolders=$True)`, but then it always works...

Comment: @DarkLite1 There is no conditional in the code you posted. Please update your question with the rest of your code. Also, `=` is an *assignment* operator in PowerShell, not a *comparison* operator. That would be `-eq`.

Comment: @DarkLite1 Evaluating the switch `-CleanFolders` in a statement `if ($CleanFolders)` worked just fine for me.

Comment: You're right, I've did a full update on the code because I didn't copy paste everything. Now you can see the full source.. The problem is that the function can't be executed by `Invoke-Command` because it's in the script block `$JobFunc`now, it only works for `Start-Job`and I can't seem to find the correct syntax for `Invoke-Command`. Sorry for the confusion...

Comment: @DarkLite1 Can't you define a scriptblock containing the function as well as the function call and use that scriptblock for both `Start-Job` and `Invoke-Command`? See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH!! I feel like such a moron! I was trying a 100 different ways to get that stuff in the `ScriptBlock`of `Invoke-Command` that I didn't came up with this solution. Thanks a million! Now figuring out how to pipe yes and no to `-CleanFolders`

Comment: Found it! Thanks a billion man! I really appreciate your help a lot, because I was really stuck here. Thank you thank you thank you :)