# How to pass string variable to invoke-expression?

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

I am running the below powershell command:

```
$cmd = "xxx.exe"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost {Invoke-Expression $cmd}
```

However I get the error:

```
Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Command' because it is null.

+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Invoke-Expression], ParameterB
indingValidationException
 + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,M
icrosoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeExpressionCommand
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the documentation for `Invoke-Command`.

Use either the `-ArgumentList` parameter or if powershell 3 see example 9 (`$Using:`).

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849719.aspx

ArgumentList Example -

```
$cmd = "xxx.exe"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost {Invoke-Expression $args[0]} -ArgumentList $cmd
```

If you use `param` in the script block you can used named arguments rather than the `$args` built-in.

Comment: Can you show me how to use ArgumentList in my case? I tried a couple of ways but no success. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to show you the way I do it, passing a file with `-FilePath` and passing the parameters with `-ArgumentList`

I create a function that is going to contain the code I want to execute.

```
#remote_functions.ps1
param($command, $param1, $param2, $param3, $param4, $param5)
$ScriptVersion = "1.0"

function Write5Strings($string1, $string2, $string3, $string4, $string5)
{
    Write-Host "String1: $string1"
    Write-Host "String2: $string2"
    Write-Host "String3: $string3"
    Write-Host "String4: $string4"
    Write-Host "String5: $string5"
    throw "ERROR"
}


try
{
    &$command $param1 $param2 $param3 $param4 $param5
}
catch [System.Exception]
{
    Write-Error $_.Exception.ToString()
    exit 1
}
```

And I invoke it this way:

```
$server="server"
$remotingPort=81

$job = Invoke-Command -AsJob -Port $remotingPort -ComputerName $server -FilePath ".\remote_functions.ps1" -ArgumentList @("Write5Strings", "apple", "banana", "orange", "pear", "watermelon")
```

Check also this question: [How do I pass named parameters with Invoke-Command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225748/how-do-i-pass-named-parameters-with-invoke-command?rq=1)