# Pass custom Parameters for & call

Tags: powershell

In Powershell I am calling a custom script:

```
 &  C:\test.ps1
```

I want to pass a custom parameter to that script. I am trying ArgumentList. But I think that only deals with predefined arguments.

```
 &  C:\test.ps1 -ArgumentList "Something"
```

I'm not sure how to pass my own custom variable to another script that I call...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27794898/powershell-pass-named-parameters-to-argumentlist/27799658?noredirect=1#comment72205135_27799658

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options in this scenario:

```
& C:\Test.ps1 -Switch1 -arg 'this is an arg'
```

Or the `Start-Process` cmdlet:

```
Start-Process -FilePath 'C:\Test.ps1' -ArgumentList @('-Switch1','-arg','this is an arg')
```

---

But this begs the question: why are you invoking a PowerShell script instead of modularizing it to a function or module to import to the script you intend to use it?

Comment: How would I call that inside the Test.ps1 script. Would it be $Switch1?

Comment: @TakafuKeyomama Could you clarify what you want to do?

Comment: @TakafuKeyomama In the first example you need to [declare the parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters) in `Test.ps1`. For the second, you can access them through `$args`