# Run an executable with a parameter using Invoke-Command

Tags: powershell, execution, invoke-command

I am trying to run an executable with a config file as a parameter using invoke-command through a PowerShell script.

Here is what I have so far in my PowerShell script:

```
$config = 'D:\EmailLoader\App.config'
invoke-command -ComputerName SERVER-NAME -ScriptBlock {param($config) & 'D:\EmailLoader\GetMailAndAttachment.exe' $config} -ArgumentList $config
```

I then Execute the PowerShell script with the following command:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File "D:\PowerShellScripts\Email.ps1"
```

And I get the following error:

```
Unexpected token 'config' in expression or statement.
At D:\PowerShellScripts\Email.ps1:3 char:121
+ invoke-command -ComputerName SERVER-NAME -ScriptBlock {param($config)     'D:\EmailLoader\GetMailAndAttachment.exe' $config <<<< } -ArgumentList $config
+ CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (config:String) [], ParentContainsE   rrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken
```

Comment: So, what is the actual problem you're facing? You described what you're trying to do (which should work AFAICS), but not what's going wrong.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I have edited the question to include the error.

Comment: I would suggest check this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225748/how-do-i-pass-named-parameters-with-invoke-command

Comment: I think I have got mixed up, the script at the top seems to run ok, the script I ran that returned the error message didn't have the & in front of the string in the ScriptBlock. Too many variations of scripts open!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code looks like it should work. But the exception message is clearly missing the `&` symbol. I would check that first, because you are getting the exact same message I would anticipate to get when the `&` was missing. So maybe there is problem with the saved file, rather than with your code.

Side note: If you are on PowerShell 3.0 or newer you should consider using the `$using:` scope in the script block to avoid adding the `param` and `-ArgumentList`.

```
$config = 'D:\EmailLoader\App.config'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName SERVER-NAME -ScriptBlock {
    &'D:\EmailLoader\GetMailAndAttachment.exe' $using:config
}
```

Comment: I think I have got mixed up, the script at the top seems to run ok, the script I ran that returned the error message didn't have the & in front of the string in the ScriptBlock. Too many variations of scripts open!

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to pass `$config` as a parameter to a `ScriptBlock`. Also not needed to add the `$config` parameter twice. This should work:

```
$config = 'D:\EmailLoader\App.config'
Invoke-Command -ComputerName SERVER-NAME -ScriptBlock {&('D:\EmailLoader\GetMailAndAttachment.exe')} -ArgumentList @($config)
```

Comment: Returns the following error:+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

Unhandled Exception:

System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at GetMailAndAttachment.GMAA.ReadConfig(String ConfigFile, String Key)
   at GetMailAndAttachment.GMAA.Main(String[] args)

Comment: I have made a change to make sure that the argumentlist is een array object. If that doesn't work then the issue is in the EmailLoader program

Comment: The error is in `GetMailAndAttachment.exe` program. You'll have to debug that program. The Powershell problem you had (calling a program) is fixed. At first glance I would say that your program expects 2 parameters (`ConfigFile` and `Key`)and you are only giving one.