# invoke-command net file close

Tags: file, powershell, invoke-command

I'm trying to close certain open files on a remote 2008 R2 fileserver with the following lines:

```
$FileList = Invoke-Command -Scriptblock { openfiles.exe /query /S fileserver01 /fo csv | where {$_.contains("sampletext")} }
foreach ($f in $FileList) {
    $fid = $f.split(',')[0]
    $fid = $fid -replace '"'
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName fileserver01 -ScriptBlock { net file $fid /close }
}
```

I can get this to work if I type it in, but when I throw it into a script, it doesn't close the files.

I've verified that the `$FileList` variable gets filled (`$fid` indeed gets the file id), so I don't think there's a execution policy that's blocking me. I'm not sure what it could be.

Answer (score 1):

I think its because your $fid variable exists only on your local session.

If you are on powershell 3 you can use "using", example:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName fileserver01 -ScriptBlock { net file $using:fid /close }
```

In powershell 2 you can use this:

[How do I pass named parameters with Invoke-Command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225748/how-do-i-pass-named-parameters-with-invoke-command)

Comment: Do you know of any documentation for the $using command? I couldn't get it to work.
I also tried throwing the command in a string and using the string, but that didn't help either. For example:

    $netfile = "net file $fid /close"

Comment: if does not work. Probably you are on a powershell v2 our v1. Then you have to use de second option.

Comment: I upgraded to version 4.0  from v2 this morning because I thought I might be running into a version problem.... :/

Comment: strange. Have you tried replace $fid to $using:fid in your last line?

Comment: yup... sure have.....
Here's my whole script.... maybe you can find something wrong with it that I've overlooked.
http://pastebin.com/uw3mUfSy

Comment: Does anyone know of some documentation for the "using" command/statement? I'm trying to find something, but since "using" is such a common word with other "uses", I'm having trouble getting anything "useful".

Comment: @michaewlewis: `Get-Help about_Scopes` and `Get-Help about_Remote_Variables`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `$fid` variable in the script block is a different variable than the `$fid` variable in your `foreach` loop.  You need to pass it in as an argument, like so:

```
foreach ($f in $FileList) {
    $fid = $f.split(',')[0]
    $fid = $fid -replace '"'
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName fileserver01 -ArgumentList $fid -ScriptBlock {
        param ($fid)
        net file $fid /close
    }
}
```

Whenever I do something like this, I usually choose a different variable name inside the script block, to avoid confusion.  The arguments in the `-ArgumentList` parameter get matched one-by-one to the variables in the `param` section, so in this example, **$fid** gets mapped to **$fileId**:

```
foreach ($f in $FileList) {
    $fid = $f.split(',')[0]
    $fid = $fid -replace '"'
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName fileserver01 -ArgumentList $fid -ScriptBlock {
        param ($fileId)
        net file $fileId /close
    }
}
```