# How to use -ArgumentList with Invoke-Command to pass flags to a script?

Tags: powershell

How to use -ArgumentList with Invoke-Command to pass flags to a script?

```
# File: ./setup.ps1

param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]   
    [alias("force")]   
    [switch]$opt_force
)

if ($opt_force) {
    write-host "FORCING something!"
}
write-host "Done"
```

Powershell Command Line:

```
PS> Invoke-Command  -Computer pv3039  -FilePath ./setup.ps1 -ArgumentList "-force"
```

Error Message:

```
 positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-force'.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound
    + PSComputerName        : pv3039
```

Comment: Just pass in $true. Since you only have the one parameter it will bind positionally. -Argumentlist $true

Comment: Unfortunately you can't pass in named parameters:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225748/how-do-i-pass-named-parameters-with-invoke-command

Answer (score 0):

If you want to call a remote script, you can use Start-Process instead of Invoke-Command. Maybe you can try something like this.

```
Start-Process PowerShell -ArgumentList "YOUR_SCRIPT_PATH\setup.ps1 -Force" -NoNewWindow -Wait
```

This way it can accept parameters from the called script.