# It returns all services even though there is one in list

Tags: powershell

I want my script to take the server and service as a list from a .txt file. After that I want my script to check that if this service exists on the servers on the txt file.

But when I run this script, it returns all of the services as it exists on the server and not the ones I specified in service list. Also it doesn't drop to catch even tho the service doesn't exist.

Can you tell me why it returns all of the services?

```
$ErrorActionPreference='stop'

$ServerList = Get-Content 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\service test\servers.txt'
$ServiceList = Get-Content 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\service test\services.txt'

try{
    foreach($Server in $ServerList){
        foreach($Service in $ServiceList){

            $Result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock {
                Get-Service -Name $Service
            }

            foreach($List in $Result){
                Write-Host "$List exists on $Server"
            }     
        }
    }
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException]
{ 
    Write-Host "Error" 
}
```

Comment: The problem is, that `$Service` is not accessible in your script block. If you change your script block to `Write-Host $Service` you will get no output. Thats why you get all services, because `Get-Service $Service` will become just `Get-Service`. You need to pass your arguments as -ArgumentList like so: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4225748/how-do-i-pass-named-parameters-with-invoke-command

Comment: you need to pass the services as an argument, or as a remote variable to be reference. You can do so using the `$using` variable: `$using:service`. . .but, `Get-Service` accepts a `-ComputerName` parameter for remote computers that you can switch it for.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala when i tried that it worked but it showed service name as something different. Like System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController

Comment: @M.G that topic seemed so advanced for me. i always struggled at part passing parameters sadly

Comment: @RedAndBlack That's because `$List` contains a `ServiceController` object. If you want to print just the name, do `Write-Host "$($List.Name) exists on $Server"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from my comment. . . when using a local variable against a remote computer in a scriptblock, you have to pass it as an argument, or have it referenced using the remote variable of `$using`.

- This is due to a new session being ran on the remote machine with no clue what `$service` is on that machine as it's never been declared on that side.
- You can pass it using the `-Arguments`, parameter. Creating a *param* block to pass it onto or, using the remote variable of [`$using`.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_variables?view=powershell-7.2)

Also, there's really no need for you to invoke the command over to the remote machine as `Get-Service` has a `-ComputerName` parameter for remote machines:

```
$ServerList = Get-Content 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\service test\servers.txt'
$ServiceList = Get-Content 'C:\Users\username\Desktop\service test\services.txt'
    foreach ($Server in $ServerList)
    {
        foreach ($Service in $ServiceList.trim())
        {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                ComputerName = $Server
                Service      = $Service 
                Exists       = if (Get-Service -Name $service -ComputerName $Server -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) { $true } else { $false }
            }           
        }
    }
```

as for what you tried:

```
$Result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Server -ScriptBlock {
                Get-Service -Name $Service
            }
```

1. `$service` (*as mentioned above*), is empty and not defined on the remote sessions scope.
2. When you switched it to `$using:service` it worked but, it returned the *type* of object and not the name itself, because you're returning the entirety of an object and not the name property. Instead, just reference the current `$service` that is being used in the loop and declare if it's there, or not.

Comment: I tried this one and it worked. But for some reason like i have a list like 
A
B
C all in seperated lines.
but the program takes the list as 'A B C' and returns false. program works well tho.

Comment: Can you elaborate some more? Not quite sure what you mean. So in your list, you have services in the same row such as: A B C? where it should be A, B, and C?

Comment: Like I have a txt file where 1st line is A, 2nd line is B, and 3rd line is C. When i run it, output comes like A B C as same line even tho i call it via for loop

Comment: Are you using my code, or your own?

Comment: I used your program

Comment: Thats odd, I don't see how that would be the case. `Get-Content` reads the file line by line, creating an array. Unless there's names in the same line, you shouldn't get that result. Can you share a snippet of your service list file?

Comment: i removed the service list from my program. instead i used arrays in the program. because i will always be searching for some specific services. it was hard but fixed my problem. thanks for your assistance. it helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

the script is not structured correctly, an no need to us the invoke command, when you can use 'get-service -computername' Also the try, catch statement would only catch the last error not each.

I changed your original script to reflect this and moved the try, catch statement to catch each error (if the service does not exist).

```
$ErrorActionPreference='stop'
$ServerList = Get-Content 'C:\temp\servicetest\servers.txt'
$ServiceList = Get-Content 'C:\temp\servicetest\services.txt'

ForEach($Server in $ServerList){
        #Get-Service -ComputerName $Server -Name 'XblAuthManager'
        ForEach($Service in $ServiceList){
            try {
                $a = Get-Service -ComputerName $Server -Name $Service
                    IF ($a) {       
                        Write-Host "Service - $Service exists on Server - $Server"
                        }
            } catch {
                    Write-Host "Service - $Service does not exist on Server - $Server"
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: it worked thanks. but if i write it in "", it says System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController. i need to remove the "" so it gives the name. thanks for the help.