# How to declare table column name as a variable in powershell script

Tags: database, azure, powershell

I am writing one powershell script to get display one record of a table from the Azure Database. I am using select query in the powershell script to fetch the specific record. I have to declare a column name as a variable from that table and I have write the if else condition to update that particular column values with the help of update query. Below is my script:

```
# Import the module
 #Import-Module -Name SqlServer

#Set Azure subscription
#az account set --subscription "subscriptionid"

#Query Needs to execute
$query = "select * from Sys_Mst_VMProperties where Name = 'test7777' and idVMProperties = 1961"

# Setup your parameters
$Params = @{
    'ServerInstance' = 'instance.database.windows.net';
    'Database' = 'dbname';
    'Username' = 'userid';
    'Password' = 'pwd';
    'Query' = $query;
}

# Splat
Invoke-Sqlcmd @Params
```

From the above output, I have the declare the VMStatus as variable and the variable should read the value from the table.

Kindly help us for above problem.

Comment: `$VMStatus = (Invoke-Sqlcmd @Params)[[int]$Row].VMStatus`, or just `$VMStatus = (Invoke-Sqlcmd @Params).VMStatus` if it concerns a single row.

Answer (score 0):

`Invoke-Sqlcmd` - It helps to run the SQL statements that supports the utility of SQL Server Sqlcmd.

As per the [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/invoke-sqlcmd?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sqlserver-ps#example-3--invoke-a-script-and-pass-in-variable-values-from-a-string), we have several example scenarios.

Like, below is the sample example for Invoke a script and pass in variable values from a string.

```
$StringA = "Var1='RAJ'", "Var2='KUMAR'" 
Invoke-Sqlcmd -Query  "SELECT `$(Var1) AS Var1, `$(Var2) AS Var2" -Variable  $String
```

***Output:***
|Var1|Var2|
|--|--|
|RAJ|KUMAR|

As per your scenario,

> I have the declare the `VMStatus` as variable and the variable should read the value from the table.

As suggested by `@iRon`, try with the mentioned two approaches it will work.

And [refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37399552/18935775), this for `invoke-command`.